# How could i get the Job Description in my java code?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

When i have Spring Batch Job Defined as the following:

```
<batch:job id="FailTask">
<batch:description>My Job Description</batch:description>
    <batch:step id="FailTask-step0">
        <batch:tasklet ref="sampleFailTask" />
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="sampleFailStepListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

**How could i get the Job Description in my java code ?**

Comment: What code did you try for getting the job?

Comment: Map<String, Job> Jobs = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Job.class);

Answer (score 1):

ok i found it:

```
AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
BeanDefinition beanDefinition = ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory).getBeanDefinition(taskName);
String taskDescription = beanDefinition.getDescription();
```

now the question is how to get other properties than Description?

Answer (score 0):

In [JobParser](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/JobParser.html) there are lines:

```
    Element description = DomUtils.getChildElementByTagName(element, "description");
    if (description != null) {
        builder.getBeanDefinition().setDescription(description.getTextContent());
    }
```

So, description is set to bean defenition. You may get it from [BeanDefinitionRegistry](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html#getBeanDefinition%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: is there any Spring util to get the element ?

Comment: not sure what you mean. Use BeanDefinitionRegistry to get BeanDefinition and getDescription for it